# Returned strings that did not match in mySQL

Tags: mysql

How do I get the remaining items in a MySQL select?
Let's say I've got this table with id and color and want to return the queried colors that did not exist in my database.

```
ID    COLOR
1     red
5     brown
33    pink
```

If I pass in a list of colors I want to get back the ones not found

`('red','brown','blue')` should return `('blue')`

and

`('yellow','pink','orange')` should return `('yellow','orange')`

I know I can accomplish this using other languages to exclude the hits from the searches array, but it would be neat to do it in a single SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your query as:

```
SELECT sub.color
FROM (SELECT 'red' AS color
      UNION ALL SELECT 'brown'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'blue') AS sub
LEFT JOIN tab
   ON sub.color = tab.color
WHERE tab.id IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9161c/5/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╗
║ color  ║
╠════════╣
║ blue   ║
╚════════╝
```

Second:

```
SELECT sub.color
FROM (SELECT 'yellow' AS color
      UNION ALL SELECT 'pink'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'orange') AS sub
LEFT JOIN tab
   ON sub.color = tab.color
WHERE tab.id IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9161c/6/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════╗
║ color  ║
╠════════╣
║ yellow ║
║ orange ║
╚════════╝
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! 
What if I want to query hundreds of colors, is there another way to solve it without having to union every color. Like a temporary table or just a temporary array?

Comment: @Teodor Yes, you can create temporary table fill with colors names and do the LEFT JOIN using `SELECT color FROM temp_table) AS sub ...`